# Is it possible to run a Macro on a Pivot Table?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a macro that will search for a string in column D and paste it into a new column. Is this possible? I noticed that it works in a non-pivoted table but I would prefer to have the macro run in a pivot table instead of converting the pivot table to raw data. Is there a variable that denotes a pivot table that I can add to the code?

The code I have so far is:

```
'1. Replace all blanks with a value 
'2. Find the keywords 
'3. Create a new row with the found keyword 
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
row_number = 0
count_of_string = 4
Do
DoEvents
row_number = row_number + 1
item_in_review = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & row_number)
    If InStr(item_in_review, "test") > 0 Then
        count_of_string = count_of_string + 1
    End If
Loop Until row_number = 60

MsgBox "Found: " & count_of_string
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, you might begin researching the [`PivotTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable) object in the docs.

Comment: Your current code seems to be recreating the wheel: use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` with `"*test*"` as the criterion, no loop required here.

Comment: https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/ shows how to refer to various ranges within a pivot table.